# How to extend Scala type signature to subclasses?

Tags: scala, oop

I defined a `Super[A]` trait with one abstract method and several concrete methods, many of which just create a new object instance with some changes. This is an example:

```
trait Super[A] { self =>

  def abstractMethod: A

  def map[B](f: A => B): Super[B] = new Super[B] {
    def abstractMethod = f(self.get)
  }
}
```

I now would like to build some classes which inherit from `Super[A]` without changing the return type of each concrete method.

What's the most idiomatic way to achieve such a result?

Comment: If you want implementation for some concrete type `A`, then you can do `class Impl extends Super[String]`, if you want implementation for some generic type `A` - you can do `class Impl[A] extends String[A]`. I do not know the whole task you are working on, but you might consider typeclasses as an alternative.

Comment: I am confused as to why would you want to change return types. Could you show an example of class which inherit from `Super[A]` where you (need to) change the return type of each concrete method?

Comment: I need each concrete method to return an instance of the concrete class as opposed to a `Super` instance

Answer (score 0):

you say you don't want to change the return type of your concrete methods, so map in this example...  I don't see any reason why you would have to change its return type.  a quick example.

note: .get wasn't defined so I used .abstractMethod in .map instead

```
trait Super[A] { self =>
  def abstractMethod: A

  def map[B](f: A => B) = new Super[B] {
    def abstractMethod = f(self.abstractMethod)
  }
}
```

a couple classes

```
class X(val n: Int) extends Super[X] {
  def abstractMethod = this
  def toY = new Y(n)
}

class Y(val n: Int) extends Super[Y] {
  def abstractMethod = this
  def toX = new X(n)
}
```

works as expected

```
val x:  X = new X(999)
val y:  Y = x.map(_.toY).abstractMethod
val x2: X = y.map(_.toX).abstractMethod

val sup_x:  Super[X] =     x.map(_.abstractMethod)
val sup_y:  Super[Y] =     x.map(_.toY)
val sup_y2: Super[Y] = sup_x.map(_.toY)
val sup_x2: Super[X] = sup_y.map(_.toX)
```